# Hadoop: Pseudo Distributed mode for multiple users

Tags: hadoop

I appreciate your help in advance.

I have setup Hadoop in Pseudo Distributed mode using the root user credentials. I want to provide access to multiple users (let us say hadoop1, hadoop2, etc) to be able to submit and run MapReduce jobs on this cluster. How do we get this done?

What I have done so far?

```
> - Setup Hadoop to run in Pseudo-distributed mode
> - Used "root" user credentials to set this up.
> - Added users hadoop1 and hadoop2 to a group called "hadoop".
> - Added root also to be part of the group "hadoop".
> - Created a folder called hdfstmp and set this as the path for hadoop.tmp.dir.
> - Started the cluster using bin/start-all.sh
> - Ran MapReduce jobs using hadoop1 and hadoop2 users.
```

I got the error below:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.io.IOException: Permission denied
        at java.io.UnixFileSystem.createFileExclusively(Native Method)
        at java.io.File.createNewFile(File.java:1006)
        at java.io.File.createTempFile(File.java:1989)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:119)
```

- To overcome this error, I gave group "hadoop" rwx permissions to folder hdfstmp. The permissions on this folder look like drwxrwxr-x.
- Submitted MapReduce jobs using hadoop1 and hadoop2 users login. The job ran fine without any errors.

However, if I do a stop-all.sh and then do a start-all.sh, the DataNode (and occassionally even NameNode) does not start up. When I check the logs, i see an error as below:

2013-09-21 16:43:54,518 WARN org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode: Invalid directory in dfs.data.dir: Incorrect permission for /data/hdfstmp/dfs/data, expected: rwxr-xr-x, while actual: rwxrwxr-x

Now, without change to the group ownership of the hdfstmp directory, my MR jobs submitted by different users do not run. But when the NameNode gets restarted, i get the issue as above.

How do i overcome this issue? What is the best practice for the same?

Also, is there a way to monitor the jobs that are being submitted by the different users? I am assuming the Web UI should allow me to do this. Please confirm.

I appreciate any assistance you can provide me on this issue. Thanks.

Regards

Comment: When you amended the tmp folder permissions - did you amend the folder on HDFS, or the local disk?

Comment: Chris - I amended on permissions on the local disk.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Adding a dedicated Hadoop system user**

We will use a dedicated Hadoop user account for running Hadoop. While that’s not required it is recommended because it helps to separate the Hadoop installation from other software applications and user accounts running on the same machine (think: security, permissions, backups, etc).

```
#addgroup hadoop
#adduser --ingroup hadoop hadoop1
#adduser --ingroup hadoop hadoop2
```

This will add the user hduser and the group hadoop to your local machine.

**Change permission of your hadoop installed directory**

```
chown -R hduser:hadoop hadoop
```

**And lastly change hadoop temporary directoy permission**

If your temp directory is /app/hadoop/tmp

```
#mkdir -p /app/hadoop/tmp
#chown hduser:hadoop /app/hadoop/tmp
```

and if you want to tighten up security, chmod from 755 to 750...

```
#chmod 750 /app/hadoop/tmp
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. Question: If my /app/hadoop/tmp directory has the rights 755, it means that only the owner 'hduser' can create files inside that directory and the members of the 'hadoop' group (hadoop1 and hadoop2 in this case) cannot create files inside this directory. Is my understanding correct? If yes, then when user hadoop1 executes a MapReduce job, the intermediate data has to be written inside the '/app/hadoop/tmp' directory, but hadoop1 does not have WRITE permissions. So, you will get a 'permission denied' error. Is my understanding correct?

Comment: If both **hadoop1** and **hadoop2** are member of **hadoop** group then they have permission to read and write the files in **/app/hadoop/tmp**. And if you get a permission denied error that means they are not member of **hadoop** group.

Comment: I am sure I have groups set up properly and hadoop user is part of the hadoop directory. I tried with 755 permissions to both the hadoop directory and the hadoop.tmp.dir directory, but it is still getting a 'Permission Denied' error. I am new to Linux, so please correct me if i am wrong: R-X does not give the user/group access to write a file in that directory, right?

Comment: @user3031097 did you ever work out the issue? I'm getting the same error with `mkdir: Permission denied: user=dijksterhuis, access=WRITE, inode="/user":hadoop:supergroup:drwxr-xr-x` as output